# Converting a beamer two-column code into one that works in a normal `article` document class?

Tags: beamer, two-column, article

I currently have code that is written for `beamer` that aligns two columns so that I can display results side by side. It is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth] % align columns
\column{.4\textwidth}
\textbf{First Entry}
$X, Y$
\medskip
\textbf{Second Entry}
$Z, W$
\medskip
\textbf{Third Entry}
\column{.55\textwidth}
Here is text corresponding to the equations in the left.
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

I am wondering how I can convert this to a normal `article` documentclass. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use `minipage`s instead of `\column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minipages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\textbf{First Entry}
$X, Y$

\medskip
\textbf{Second Entry}
$Z, W$

\medskip
\textbf{Third Entry}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
Here is text corresponding to the equations in the left.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```